# Play sound when a word spoken is in command

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit, pyttsx3

I want to code a script for example

If 'song' in command:
Playsound(path)
Speak(path)

It should work like. When speech recognition is imported and when i run script, it starts listening and when i say a trigger word the audio of given path startsplaying

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the python module `pyttsx3` for text to speech. You can just pass a string through to the engine and will use a voice (which you can change) to speak it out in one of those robotic voices.

For example:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

If you are looking merely for being able to run .wav, .mpf, or other sound files such as songs I'd recommend checking out the `playsound` module

Here's an example of that below:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('audio.mp3')
```

Comment: I want to use this playsound command with a condition of if statement